# Duplicate values in Ocaml

Tags: queue, duplicates, ocaml

How do you delete repeated values (i.e. duplicates) from a queue in Ocaml?

For example, suppose this is a queue (although it is presented in the form of a list):

```
     [1; 1; 2; 3; 4; 7; 7; 8; 8; 8]
```

Then, after applying this function to the queue, we would get:

```
     [1; 2; 3; 4; 7; 8]
```

Implementation in the case of lists:

```
     let rec deleteDuplicate l = 
        match l with 
         | []                -> [] 
         | x :: []          -> x :: [] 
         | x :: y :: rest -> 
               if x = y then deleteDuplicate (y :: rest) 
               else x :: deleteDuplicate (y :: rest)
```

Comment: I'm just curious to know. I tried implementing it, but everything did not come close to what I wanted. I implemented it for lists, quite an easy task, but I was unable to do the same thing for queues.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're thinking of as the difference between a list and a queue. If you have a queue, you can transform into a list by repeatedly extracting the first element. You can transform a list into a queue by repeatedly appending the head of the list to the queue. It would help to see some code, working or not. In particular, it would be good to see how you're representing your queue.

Comment: I edited the question, so it would be easier to see than in this comment section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the first thing to do is to decide how you're going to represent your queues. You can use the Queue module that's part of the standard OCaml library. This uses a mutable representation for the queue. Or you can use a very nice (simple but clever) immutable representation that consists of two lists, one for the head and a reversed one for the tail. After you decide on your representation, I suspect it will be easy to see what to do. You had no trouble doing it for a list.

Let's say you want to use the Queue module from the OCaml library. Since this is a mutable queue, I'll assume you want to code in imperative style. I.e., you want to modify an existing queue so that duplicates are removed.

One very straightforward way to do this is to transform to a list first, then apply your function to the list, then put the elements back into the queue.

```
let rec list_of_queue q =
    (* Change queue to list, emptying queue in the process.
     *)
    if Queue.is_empty q then [] else let h = Queue.take q in h :: list_of_queue q

let queue_add_list q l =
    List.iter (fun x -> Queue.add x q) l

let deleteQueueDuplicates q =
    let l = list_of_queue q in
    queue_add_list q (deleteDuplicate l)
```

Comment: What if I wanted to use the same representation as the one used in the Ocaml library?